# JUnit test won't run when I Run-As from the test.java file

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

I have a rather odd problem w/ JUnit4 and Eclipse.

I have a Quaternion.java file, and an associated QuaternionTest.java.  In the package explorer, I can right click on the (C) icon under the QuaternionTest.java file and Run-As JUnit.  The test runs as expected.  When I right click on the QuaternionTest.java file and try to run the test, I get the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching java".
Path must include project and resource name: /QuaternionTest.java
```

I'm new to Eclipse and JUnit, so forgive me if this is supposed to be obvious.  I've tried looking at the properties and don't see anything.  Also, if I exclude QuaternionTest.java from my build path, everything runs fine (except, of course, the Quaternion tests)

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: You mean it does not run when you click in the source code editor? No wonder you are frustrated.... all I can offer is "works for me".  Are you in the Java perspective?  Do you have the source folder under which the package containing the test file in the build path?

Comment: attempting to run it from the source code editor will cause this error as well.  I have lots of other tests in this project, and they all run fine.  The only difference that I can see with this one is that it extends an abstract test case for some setup stuff.  Yes I'm in the Java perspective.

Comment: I don't know why extending an abstract test class would matter.  If running it from Pacakge Explorer works, you can stick with that.  In fact running all tests in your `src/test/java` can be done by right clicking on that directory.  I always run my tests in bulk this way for one-offs (though of course I have maven for the whole thing).  Also once the JUnit view is up you can just rerun by clicking the little green arrow or using the hotkeys.

Comment: I removed the extending the abstract... didn't work.  I can't run from the src/test/java folder... when I do, I get the error and none of the tests run.  The only way I can get everything else to run from src/test/java is to exclude the test from the build.  Even worse, when I make a new file and put the tests in the new file... it still doesn't work.  If I could tag this with [frustration*5] I would.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sort of problem is always difficult to debug without your full environment, but it sounds like you have a Run Configuration which is corrupted or doesn't match your classes or something like that. Try deleting the Run Configuration and retrying.

When you select Run As JUnit, Eclipse creates a Run Configuration specific to your JUnit class.

To fix this, in Eclipse, open Run->Run Configuration. In the list at the left, find the run configuration that applies to QuaternionTest, make sure it's the Run Configuration in the JUnit section. Delete it (right click, select delete). Then try again.

[image]

Comment: good info, but this wasn't my problem.  Something in the test case was causing this, and I have no idea what it was.  I removed one function and all of a sudden things worked.  I don't have time right now to diagnose it, so I just moved on.  I'll mark this as the answer because it's probably what most people are going to run into and has good info about Test configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with this problem for an hour and finally I got it worked by going to run configuration->JUnit->yourTest. In your test setting change the test runner and it works.

Comment: Yes, starting a testcase with Test Runner "Junit5" resulted in a "finished after x seconds" message, but with an execution of "0/0" testcases. Starting the same testcase with Test Runner "Junit4" executed the testcase as expected. After switching back to Test Runner "Junit5", Eclipse executed no testcase at all. Strange, but your answer helped me executing. Thanks! :-)

Comment: After migrating the JUnit testcases from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, Eclipse also executes testcases with Test Runner "JUnit5". You have to import JUnit 5, switch import from org.junit.Test to org.junit.jupiter.api.Test and org.junit.Assert to org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.